# conditional logic in oracle control files

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Im having a problem making a conditional statement in a control file loaded by sqlldr. For some reason when i try saying When article_length<50, it gives the error "Illegal use of non-alphanumeric characters. If i change the '<' to a '=' it changes the error to looking for quoted string or hex, found "50". What am i doing wrong?

```
    LOAD DATA
INFILE h3.csv
insert
INTO Table H3_Authors_temp
fields terminated by ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' AND '"'
( 
Author_ID,field1 FILLER, First_Name, Last_Name,Gender,Email
)
into table H3_fiction_short when ARTICLE_LENGTH < 50 AND ARTICLE_TYPE="fiction"
(
AUTHOR_ID INTEGER, field1 FILLER varchar(30), FIRST_NAME FILLER varchar(30), LAST_NAME FILLER varchar(30), GENDER FILLER varchar(30),
Email FILLER varchar(30), Issue_Num INTEGER, ARTICLE_TYPE Filler varchar(30), ARTICLE_NAME, ARTICLE_LENGTH INTEGER, 
PAYMENT_RATE FLOAT, DATE_SUBMITTED DATE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One error I see is using double quotes instead of single around 'fiction'.

Comment: actually thats fine, if you remove the part that says "ARTICLE_LENGTH = 50 AND, Then it works  just fine.

Comment: Oh tell you what, do you need quotes around the 50? the examples in the docs have them even for numerics: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_control_file.htm#i1005657

Comment: tried that, also the first example i see with numerics doesn't have quotes.

Comment: Ugh. Out of idea, sorry. Other than to dump SQL*Loader and use external tables -- much easier and more flexible.